# Show that $\operatorname{div}(f∇g) = f∇^2g + ∇f \cdot ∇g$ where $f$ and $g$ are scalar functions.

Tags: calculus

Show that $\operatorname{div}(f∇g) = f∇^2g + ∇f \cdot ∇g$ where $f$ and $g$ are scalar functions.

How can I verify this?

Answer (score 2):

You can proceed by direct computation
$$
\mathrm{div}(f\nabla g)=\sum_{j=1}^n\partial_j(f\partial_jg)=\sum_{j=1}^n
(\partial_jf\partial_jg+f\partial_{jj}g)=\nabla f\cdot\nabla g+f\Delta g.$$

Answer (score 1):

Have you encountered the equality $div(\phi \vec F)=\nabla\phi.\vec F+\phi div(\vec F)$? Direct application I think that should give you what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the properties of the operator $\nabla.$ In particular here a product rule has been used. Then the left hand side is $$\nabla \cdot f\nabla g=f\nabla\cdot \nabla g+\nabla g\cdot\nabla f=f\nabla^2g+\nabla g\cdot\nabla f.$$